# fa-border with fa-fw, wrong alignment inside border

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to create a few icons using `fa-fw` and `fa-border`, to get them to have the same width and with a border. I have tried using `fa-stack`, but that is no longer an option.

When using only `fa-border` the icon inside is placed in the center of the border, but using `fa-fw` will make the icon align to the right inside of the border, at least on some icons, like this one

```
<i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-fw fa-3x fa-border"></i>
```

[Simple plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pnTg7KLILUIVojVUenl?p=preview) to demonstrate

How can I get the icon to be in the center of the border, using both `fa-fw` and `fa-border`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the css, the `fa-fw` class gives the `<i/>` element a fixed-width of around 1.3em. But the `fa-3x` class sets the font-size to 3em. That's why it looks like the icon is pushed to the right side, but in fact the container is too small for the icon.

Basically what you need is your own custom `fa-fw-3x` class. Something like this:

```
.fa-fw-3x { width: 3.3em; }
```

Fiddle around with the width to find out what you need.

Comment: I wasn't able to set the width on the specific size like `.fa-fw-3x` but it was possible on `.fa-fw` and that was all I needed, thanks!

Comment: @klskl it probably got overwritten by some other style (did you use class `fa-fw` as well?). If you use the `!important` keyword it'll fix it. But hey whatever, it works now ;)

Comment: ye, it's `fa-fw` and `fa-3x` (not `fa-fw-3x` all in one), but yes, it works very well